# Download complete website (including assets) for offline use

Tags: javascript, cordova, offline

I'm thinking of writing a Cordova app which downloads websites so they can be read offline (like HTTrack for Windows). The main reason is lack of a good offline RSS reader for Windows 10 tablets.

I know in general what I would have to do but is there some framework which could simplify some of it?

So far I think I would need to do the following:

- Download the HTML of a site
- Get a list of all assets (CSS, JS, images, videos)
- Download those assets
- Replace asset URLs with new local ones.

The biggest problem is downloading the assets. It's not as straight forward as parsing the HTML for `link`, `script`, and `img` tags since CSS could have `imports` and JS could have ajax calls.
Also, how to decide which assets to download? I wouldn't want to waste time downloading ads..

Also there are some specific questions:

- How should I display a downloaded page? My first thought is in an iFrame to prevent collisions.
- Are there any legal problems? Especially if I were to publish the app?
- How could I save the assets so they have a URL for including in the HTML?
- Might it be better using a server to do the heavy lifting (parsing, rewriting, getting URLs etc.)? Are there tools for this already?

Does anyone have any pointers? Or do you think it's impractical?

Comment: if you developed a cordova application from it then it will be big size app who will download it .So please inappbrowser simply.

Comment: I don't want to package websites inside the app, I want to give the user the ability to save sites locally to read offline. Many RSS readers already offer this.

Comment: **Update**: [html-screen-capture-js](https://github.com/html-screen-capture-js/html-screen-capture-js) inlines external assets and generates a single HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://archivebox.io, it's an open-source, self-hosted tool that creates a local, static, browsable HTML clone of websites (it saves HTML, JS, media files, PDFs, screenshot, static assets and more).

It does most of what you want, including saving assets and media files with youtube-dl, wget, and chrome headless.